# yajra/laravel-datatables search is not working with laravel 5.7

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables, laravel-5.7

Here is join code and assign `Datatables`

```
Route::get('Productos',function(){
  $query = DB::table('producto as e')
         ->select('e.cod_producto', 'e.nom_producto', 'e.precio_venta', 'd.nombre as nombre_marca', 'j.nombre as nombre_tipo', DB::raw('if(e.estado = 0,\'Activo\',\'Eliminado\') as estado'))
         ->join('marca as d','e.cod_marca', '=', 'd.cod_marca')
         ->join('tipo-producto as j', 'e.cod_tipo_producto', '=', 'j.cod_tipo_producto');

    return datatables()
              ->of($query)
              ->addColumn('btn','actions')
              ->rawColumns(['btn'])
              ->toJson();

});
```

Here is jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Productos').DataTable({
      "bAutoWidth": false,
       "destroy": true,
       "responsive": true,
       "serverSide":true,
       "ajax":'{{url('api/Productos')}}',
       "columnDefs": [ {
         "targets": 'no-sort',
         "orderable": false,
         "searchable": false,
       }],
       "columns":[
         {data: 'cod_producto'},
         {data: 'nom_producto'},
         {data: 'precio_venta'},
         {data: 'nombre_marca'},
         {data: 'nombre_tipo'},
         {data: 'estado'},
         {data: 'btn'},
       ]
    });
});
```

Now when i try to search something it is giving me alert with error Here is an error message

> Exception Message:↵↵SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1583 Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'LOWER' (SQL:
>   select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from
>   `producto` as `e` inner join `marca` as `d` on `e`.`cod_marca` =
>   `d`.`cod_marca` inner join `tipo-producto` as `j` on
>   `e`.`cod_tipo_producto` = `j`.`cod_tipo_producto` where
>   (LOWER(`producto` as `e.cod_producto`) LIKE %1% or LOWER(`producto` as
>   `e.nom_producto`) LIKE %1% or LOWER(`producto` as `e.precio_venta`)
>   LIKE %1% or LOWER(`marca`.`nombre`) LIKE %1% or
>   LOWER(`tipo-producto`.`nombre`) LIKE %1% or LOWER(`producto` as
>   `e.estado`) LIKE %1%)) count_row_table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your Datatable columns name base on your join data field from your query

Here is the sample

```
 "columns":[
     {data: 'cod_producto', name:'e.code_product'},
     {data: 'nom_producto', name:'e.nom_producto'},
    ....
```

Comment: some of your name didn't specified correctly
like {data: 'nombre_tipo', name: 'nombre_tipo'} it must be {data: 'nombre_tipo', name: 'j.nombre'}

Comment: read some of the answer here https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/899

Comment: Thank u very much <3

Comment: this is for join more tables but i have single table query builder that is not working search option same error

Answer (score 0):

```
hai i have a same problem, this my datatable :
public function yajra(Request $request)
    {
        DB::statement(DB::raw('set @rownum=0'));
        $pengeluaran = DB::table('pengeluaran as a')->join('jenis_pengeluaran as b','a.jenis_pengeluaran', '=','b.id')->select([
            DB::raw('@rownum  := @rownum  + 1 AS rownum'),
            'a.id',
            'a.tanggal',
            'a.no_nota',
            'a.uraian',
            'a.jumlah',
            'a.jenis_pengeluaran',
            'b.nama']);
        $datatables = Datatables::of($pengeluaran)->addColumn('action', function ($pl) {
                $url_edit = url('pengeluaran/'.$pl->id);
                $url_hapus = url('pengeluaran/'.$pl->id);
                return '<a href="'.$url_edit.'" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"> <i class="ni ni-ruler-pencil"></i>Edit</a> <a href="'.$url_hapus.'" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-hapus" style="color:red;"> <i class="ni ni-fat-remove" style="color:red;"></i>Hapus</a>';
            })->editColumn('jumlah', function($pl){
                $jumlah = $pl->jumlah;
                $jumlah = number_format($jumlah,0);
                $jumlah = str_replace(',', '.', $jumlah);
                return $jumlah;
            })->editColumn('tanggal', function($pl){
                $tanggal = $pl->tanggal;
                $tanggal = date('d M Y', strtotime($tanggal));
                return $tanggal;
            });

        if ($keyword = $request->get('search')['value']) {
            $datatables->filterColumn('rownum', 'whereRaw', '@rownum  + 1 like ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
        }

        return $datatables->make(true);
    }

and this is my javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#peng').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ url('pengeluaran/yajra')}}",
        columns: [
            // or just disable search since it's not really searchable. just add searchable:false
            {data: 'rownum', name: 'rownum'},
            {data: 'tanggal', name: 'tanggal'},
            {data: 'no_nota', name: 'no_nota'},
            {data: 'uraian', name: 'uraian'},
            {data: 'jumlah', name: 'jumlah'},
            {data: 'nama', name: 'nama'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ]
    });
i'm using "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0" and laravel 7
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.